# SQLAlchemy: How to print a log of all the added or updated rows in a session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

At the end of a session, before closing, I would like to print a summary of the total rows added and/or updated during that session.

I know that I can print each SQL query with logging, for example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

However, the log file would be too large for thousands of queries.

Instead I would just like to print out the totals.

Cheers.

Comment: You could probably device something together using [events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the session's new and dirty instances before commit to count them.

```
for instance in session.new:
    add_to_new_count(instance)
for instance in session.dirty:
    if session.is_modified(instance):
        add_to_update_count(instance)
```